# I can't clone objects at the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was making a weird chunk system for my game but when I run the project it makes the floors go far away from my player position if you know the solution please tell me also here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Generate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;
    public GameObject[] floor = new GameObject[1];
    private List<float> id = new List<float>();
    public float offset = 5;
    public float times=6f;
    public float yopset=1f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
            for (float xi = (Mathf.Ceil(player.transform.position.x) - offset); xi < (Mathf.Ceil(player.transform.position.x) + offset); xi++)
            {
                for (float zi = (Mathf.Ceil(player.transform.position.z) - offset); zi < (Mathf.Ceil(player.transform.position.z) + offset); zi++)
                {
                    if (id.Contains(zi * xi))
                    {
                        if (transform.Find("floor").transform.position.x != (xi * zi) / zi & transform.Find("floor").transform.position.z != (xi * zi) / xi)
                        {
                            GameObject floors = Instantiate(floor[0], new Vector3(xi * -times, Mathf.Ceil(player.transform.position.y) - yopset, zi * times), floor[0].transform.rotation);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        GameObject floors = Instantiate(floor[0], new Vector3(xi * -times,Mathf.Ceil(player.transform.position.y)-yopset, zi * times), floor[0].transform.rotation);
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your prototypes are on 0,0,0?